# How to check if a Facebook page (others) is a FAN Page or a Personal Page?

Tags: php, mysql, facebook, facebook-like

First I like to thank everyone for the great questions and answers. Almost everything I like to know I am able to find here.

For now I am having a question :

Currently I am building a site with PHP, MySQL etc and for all my 'contacts' I am showing a Facebook 'like' Button. Some of those 'contacts' do not have a FAN page you are able to 'like', but just a regular personal account.

Is it possible somehow to check, before I am showing the 'like' button if it is a FAN page or just a regular page ?

Example :

This one I can like : https://www.facebook.com/Van.Lennep.Verhuur.Curacao

But another one is not 'accepting it : https://www.facebook.com/jankoklodges.lodges

But in both cases the 'like' button is showing up .. Any ideas ? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You could use facebook graph api or simply call:

http://graph.facebook.com/Van.Lennep.Verhuur.Curacao

or

http://graph.facebook.com/jankoklodges.lodges

first one will is a facebook page so it will return nr of likes ("likes": 333,) and other page related data, second one is a profile account so will return user related data. You could check which one is page using this and display your data accordingly.

Returned data from pages are in json format.